# Hide parent DIV if child class has no value

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to hide each Parent DIV for each value that is empty or has no text. For example, if the fruits PHP value didn't return anything, I would like it's parent DIV hidden.

```
    <div>
    <span><font size="6" color="green"><u>FRUITS</u></font></span>
    <br>
    <span class="salad"><?php echo $row1['fruits']; ?></span>
    <br><br>
    </div>  

    <div>
    <span><font size="6" color="green"><u>VEGGIES</u></font></span> 
    <br>
    <span class="salad"><?php echo $row1['veggies']; ?></span>
    <br><br>    
    </div>
```

Comment: parent or sibling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it with an IF condition :

```
<?php if($row1['fruits']) { ?>
 <div>
    <span><font size="6" color="green"><u>FRUITS</u></font></span>
    <br>
    <span class="salad"><?php echo $row1['fruits']; ?></span>
    <br><br>
    </div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Check if variable is `empty` and add a style:

```
<div <?=empty($row1['fruits'])? ' style="display:none;"' : ''?>>
<span><font size="6" color="green"><u>FRUITS</u></font></span>
<br>
<span class="salad"><?php echo $row1['fruits']; ?></span>
<br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if value is null then hide the div

```
 <div <?php if(empty($val['fruits']))){ echo 'style="display:none;"'; }else{ echo ''; }?>>
<span><font size="6" color="green"><u>Fruit</u></font></span>
<br>
<span class="salad"><?php echo $val['fruits']; ?></span>
<br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if condition. if you are sure that $row1['fruits'] may return a null value , u can use @ in-front of the variable to suppress the warning also. Hope this helps to sort your issue.

```
<?php if(@$row1['fruits']): ?>
 <div>
    <span><font size="6" color="green"><u>FRUITS</u></font></span>
    <br>
    <span class="salad"><?php echo $row1['fruits']; ?></span>
    <br><br>
    </div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```